# Why is pyodbc trying to load libtk.so?

Tags: matplotlib, odbc, tk-toolkit, pyodbc, anaconda

I am trying to load from a OneTick database via pyodbc. My code runs fine on Windows via "windows ODBC" and I am now trying to run on Linux via unixODBC.
The error I'm getting is pretty strange and looks like pyodbc is trying to load libtk:

```
<ipython-input-9-a11e7feab872> in <module>()
  1 get_ipython().magic(u'pdb')
----> 2 conn.execute("SELECT * FROM OTQ_FILES.MyOtq::tbl1 otq WHERE otq.TIMESTAMP >= '2014-12-17 09:49:00' AND otq.TIMESTAMP < '2014-12-17 09:51:00'")

Error: ('HY000', "[] [unixODBC]OmdODBC - ERROR : SQLExecDirect : ERROR: /home/nick/anaconda/pkgs/matplotlib-1.4.0-np19py27_0/lib/libtk.so doesn't exist or can't be opened (-1) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

Any ideas what is going on here? I am running via iPython using the Anaconda distribution.

Comment: I think this is an anaconda issue as the broken soft link should point to the actual `so` provided by the package `tk`.  I would try some conbination of `conda install tk --force` and `conda install matplotlib --force` and `conda upgrade --all` (or what ever the upgrade call is, I may have it wrong off the top of my head).

Comment: I have no idea why any of this is trying to import matplotlib though...

Comment: Thanks @tcaswell. Unfortunately this box is behind a firewall so its not easy to upgrade. It seems the OneTick ODBC driver is very temperamental and expects fields in the WHERE clause to be in a particular order. I can now get my query to work, however, whenever it tries to throw an error, i get this message about TK. Strange.

Comment: Hi @nickos556, did you try to contact support@onetick.com with this issue? We will fix the problem with the OneTick ODBC driver (if there is one and if we can reproduce it). Another suggestion: have you tried using OneTick's out of the box python examples with the regular Python? Do you still see the same dependency on the order of WHERE clauses? Thanks, Kirill